# Visualizar de forma descendente los registros guardados en Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

En mi código a través de un recycler view visualizo los registros cargados en Firebase Realtime database de forma descendente, pero al tratarse de registros de fecha los registros deseo ver en orden ascendente es decir que los primeros en visualizar sean las últimas fechas

A continuación muestro mi código:

```
    private void Cargar_Ordeños()
    {
        String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Query ordeñoRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ORDEÑO_DIARIO")
                .child(id).child(Txt_Numero_Animal.getText().toString()).endAt(Txt_Numero_Animal.getText().toString());

        ordeñoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Ordeño_Diario> options =
                            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Ordeño_Diario>()
                                    .setQuery(ordeñoRef, Ordeño_Diario.class)
                                    .build();

                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ordeño_Diario, Ordeno_Diario_View_Holder> adapter =
                            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ordeño_Diario, Ordeno_Diario_View_Holder>(options) {
                                @Override
                                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Ordeno_Diario_View_Holder holder, int i, @NonNull Ordeño_Diario model)
                                {
                                    holder.Txt_Fecha_Ordeño.setText(model.getFecha_Ordeño());
                                    holder.Txt_Numero_Ordeños.setText(model.getNumero_Ordeños() + " / día");
                                    holder.Txt_Cantidad_Ordeño.setText(model.getCantidad_Ordeño() + " Litros");
                                    holder.Txt_Hora_Ordeño.setText(model.getHora());
                                    holder.Txt_Nombre_Ganado.setText(model.getNombre_Ganado());
                                    holder.Txt_Numero_Ganado.setText(model.getNumero_Ganado());

                                }

                                @NonNull
                                @Override
                                public Ordeno_Diario_View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                                {
                                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.modelo_registro_leche, parent, false);
                                    Ordeno_Diario_View_Holder holder = new Ordeno_Diario_View_Holder(view);
                                    return holder;
                                }
                            };

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.startListening();
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error)
            {

            }
        });
    }
```

Obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría que el último registro se encuentre primero en la lista.

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta al problema y en donde generé el cambio fue en el linearlayout de la siguiente manera:

```
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

De esta manera el listado de firebase se visualiza de forma descendente